# UILabel background color with word wrap

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I would like to set a background "overlay" for my UILabel, and have it to only color the part of the label with text, instead of the entire rectangle. See the image below.

[image]

What is the best way for this to be done?

Comment: You could create a category that splits the `UILabel` into two separate ones with separate widths based on the desired maximum width, and you'd calculate the Y position of the second one using the height of the first.